# scrollTop doesn´t work on site change

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

On my site I have the Problem that when I´m coming from the Imprint or How-to-find-us Site and I click on service or contact, the scrollTop doesn´t work correktly.

http://wicker-schuetz.de/en/

thanks

Comment: Please post relevent code in your question.

Comment: I´m using a Wordpress-Template. I´m not sure where the Problem is. When I delete the jQuery-isotope-plugin then it Worked. But it destroy the rest of the Template :/

Answer (score 0):

It's doing that because when you get to that point on the page, there's no more room for the page to scroll up any further; because your footer is kind of stuck to the bottom of the page.

You need to add some padding to the bottom of your footer to allow some extra space for your page to scroll up. You can do that by either adding a line to your css:

```
#footer { padding-bottom: 40%; }
```

or by adding a line to your javascript file:

```
document.getElementById("footer").style.paddingBottom="40%";
```

Either one should work, but If you want to dynamically adjust the padding on the bottom of the footer, so that the padding is just right, based upon the screen size, you might want to take a look at javascript's window [onresize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onresize) and adjust the padding accordingly. Or you could probably just use [CSS3 media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries).

Comment: When you say it's longer than you need, do you mean that you want the footer to stay on the bottom of the page? If so, you there are several things you could, like add some padding to the bottom of the contact div instead of adding padding to the footer. `#contact{ padding-bottom: 30%; }`.

Comment: is it possible to cut the page at the end of the footer?